# Trying to put my first app up, but I can't because there is no distribution tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I am following this tutorial on how to put app up on app store and under targets there is suppose to be  a distribution tab not a release tab. Can someone please help me out and show me what to do. I Would really appreciate it. Instead of release it has to be distribution.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbabzWVvcvE
Here is the tutorial.

Comment: Which tutorial? You haven't included the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which tutorial you are following, but what you really have to do is make sure the target is a "device" even if it is not connected, and then go to Product>Archive after that it is pretty much a wizard and you can publish it from there.

Note: Your target must have your distribution provisioning profile already to be signed, or archive will fail.

Comment: how do i maker sure my target has distribution provisioning file  signed. I am trying to do this tutorial that involves me going in code signing and going to the distribution tab,but there is only a release tab.

Comment: @MonicaElizabeth I believe the tutorial is referring to the distribution tab in developer.apple.com which is where you generate the distribution profile you need to sign your app.

Comment: i thought i already did this, thus the reason i can use the app on my iPod touch.

Comment: Im trying to get  my app on app store and when I get to the part of tutorial where it says in code signing you have to have a distribution tab in your app instead of a release tab.someone else came across this error in the comment section very top one.

Comment: @MonicaElizabeth The fact that you can use your app in your iPod Touch, does not indicate that you have the distribution profile, just that you have the developer profile, there are 2 types, and you will need the distribution to put your app in the AppStore.